# UITableViewCell how to change UIImageView when row is touched?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have `UIImageView` in a custom `TableViewCell`. I load an image in it with this code:

```
UIImageView *myImg = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kImagePlayer];
myImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"player_play.png"];
```

So my question is how to change this image when I touch the row? I need to change the image to "music_play".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *myImg = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kImagePlayer];
myImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"player_play.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this will help

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *tempCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     UIImageView *myImg = (UIImageView *)[tempCell viewWithTag:kImagePlayer];
     myImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"music_play.png"];
}
```

BR, Hari

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which row was selected using the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and find the row selected using

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then you set the new image to it.